# Qual tipo de certificado digital devo usar?

Tags: certificado-digital, clickonce

Eu possuo um pequeno projeto em c# utilizando CLickOnce para publicação.

Eu gostaria de saber qual tipo de certificado digital devo usar (se necessário onde comprar...), ou como posso fazer (se é que pode ser feito fora de uma empresa que trabalhe com isso...) para que o nome do editor apareça e a smartscreen do windows 8/10 não  mostre ele como um programa malicioso.

Imagem ilustrativa do 'problema':
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não sei ao certo como fazer, mas talvez estes links lhe ajudem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4eace3(VS.80).aspx